# Going from AspNet Identity Release Candidate to RTM

Tags: asp.net-identity

I am missing IIdentityManagerFactory , is the replacement UserManager ?

I am also having trouble finding the replacement for `LocalLoginProvider = UserManager.Settings.GetIdentityOptions().LocalLoginProvider`,

and this one

```
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.Logins.AddLocalLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(),
    User.Identity.GetUserName(), model.NewPassword);
```

I am missing a replacement for  `IdentityAuthenticationOptions options = identityManager.Settings.GetAuthenticationOptions();`

to create the ClaimsIdentity for external login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IdentityOptions are gone, all the options regarding the claims configuration now live on the ClaimsIdentityFactory that hangs off of the UserManager.  There is no longer a UserManager factory for RTM, so you would have to define your own factory interface if needed.  For Update 1, we will likely have an owin middleware piece that the UserManager for the request will hang off of.

Regarding the "local" provider, that concept was removed from the core, users can optionally have passwords, which map the the concept of a local user (HasPassword instead).

Comment: Thanks. I managed to update the template from vs 2013 rc. Think there was a few lines that i commented out as I didnt find a replacement.  My udated code is here for anyone else who can use it for inspiration. https://github.com/s093294/aspnet-identity-rtm